# Are these tires worn out or was it rather a manufacturing defect?

Tags: tire, wear

On both of my tires (conti [0101442 or 0100175](https://www.continental-tires.com/bicycle/tires/race-tires/grand-prix-4-season), can't remember), I got a fissure running almost uninterrupted all the circumference. It's not in the middle, but rather shifted to the left, on both of them.

They are two or three years old. The bicycle is stored on a wheel hook, tires do not touch anything. The shelter is fume-free.

I wonder what is it likely: wear, manufacturing defect, over-pressure?
[image: fissure]

[image]

**Edit**: Thanks for all the replies. They reminded me that the tires were sold folded several times. I'm not saying that it led to the defect, though. I tended to inflate to the upper pressure limit (and never bothered to compensate for afternoons warmer than mornings etc)
[image: retail package]

Comment: How old are they? How/where have they been stored?

Comment: "Dry rot", as it is know, is common on tyres that have been stored for a long time, possibly one part of the tyre folded. When you then pump the tyres up, the rubber splits. This looks like that to me

Comment: My vote is for manufacturing defect. Note how the split is exactly where the edge of the puncture protection strip is supposed to be.

Comment: I’ve never heard of this happening due to high pressure. The opposite is much more likely. Lots of “flexing“ if you run low pressure.

Comment: It could be over- as well as underpressure. I think you should send the picture to Conti's customer service. Especially since the fissure occurs on both tyres. It might be a manufacturing defect in which case they'd have more of this feed-back.

Comment: Riding under-inflated or storing in an area where petroleum fumes are strong would be the two things you might have done to cause this.  But a manufacturing defect seems likely.

Comment: It should be noted that "folding" tires are notoriously short-lived.  To facilitate the folding they must be made rather flimsily, with several shortcuts taken which weaken the tire.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like age/exposure related failure from what I can see. If it is a defect the shop where you purchased them may pro-rate them on new tires. If they do this it would be a good will gesture on their part. I worked in the retail automotive tire world and it is nearly impossible to get a defect related replacement from the manufacturer. They blame under /over inflation, road hazard, sun exposure etc.

Comment: I would also add that you have no idea how long the tires have been sitting in a display prior to sale. So it is hard to say how old the tires actually are or how they were stored.